How to generate a line number based on condition
I have an InvoiceLineItem table where line number is not added to the table. I have to create it on the fly while processing the table.
The line items can be grouped by

Invoice Id and
Row that end with a pattern PO[0-9]

This is my table

I am expecting the results to be

I do not have any idea how to achieve this.
I tried using the rownumber function but it does not give the expected results.
SELECT
        Invoice,
        PurchaseOrderNumber,
        Quantity,
        UnitPrice,
        LineItemTotal,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Invoice ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM
        InvoiceLineItems
    WHERE
        PurchaseOrderNumber NOT LIKE 'PO%' and Template = 'cw_engineering'

Union 

 SELECT
        Invoice,
        PurchaseOrderNumber,
        NULL AS Quantity,
        NULL AS UnitPrice,
        NULL AS LineItemTotal,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Invoice ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM
        InvoiceLineItems
    WHERE
        PurchaseOrderNumber LIKE 'PO%' and Template = 'cw_engineering'
ORDER BY
    Invoice, RN, PurchaseOrderNumber;

It works if I have 2 records for each line number.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

And please format you code as code using the option in the editor.

The data in your screenshots appear to be sorted. Do you have some identifiers in your table e.g. ID column?

Yes, it does have an auto-increment Id field. I ordered it by Invoice and Id field so that it look presentable

Then change it to ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Invoice ORDER BY ID) AS R

Sounds like you want to use gaps and islands style of query which creates a new gap every time your PO-number changes.

Of course the real solution would be to fix the table design of your data, so you don't mimic a invoice "look" but create proper rows and move the other kind of data somewhere else

Actually, maybe gaps and islands is overkill, you can just do: select COUNT(CASE WHEN PurchaseOrderNumber LIKE 'PO%' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Invoice ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), * FROM yourtable

Yep, the table design is terrible. Make this separate invoice and lines tables with a proper 1:n relation (foreign key).

These data are from the InvoiceLineItem table.
Since the data are scanned from actual invoices, we have no other choice but to load them in invoice and invoicelineitem tables.

@siggemannen this solution works. Thanks.

data
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(
   Invoice             INTEGER  NOT NULL  
  ,PurchaseOrderNumber VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
  ,Quantity            INTEGER 
  ,UnitPrice           NUMERIC(5,2)
  ,LineltemTotal       INTEGER 
);
INSERT INTO TABLE1
(Invoice,PurchaseOrderNumber,Quantity,UnitPrice,LineltemTotal) VALUES 
(120,'P2037351818419',500,18.31,9155),
(120,'PO20240091',NULL,NULL,NULL),
(120,'P2037351818420',500,6.54,3270),
(120,'PO20240091',NULL,NULL,NULL),
(120,'P203735181823782',400,2.83,1132),
(120,'4',NULL,NULL,NULL),
(120,'PO20240060',NULL,NULL,NULL),
(120,'P203735181823783',400,3.36,1344),
(120,'5',NULL,NULL,NULL),
(120,'PO20240060',NULL,NULL,NULL);

you should fill null values forward,however the result that you want needs forward and backward so its impossible to get your desired result.
use  fill null values forwardrule ,case,like,count and multiple subquery
as follows
select  idn,
  dense_rank() over(order by id3) id,
  Invoice,
  PurchaseOrderNumber,
  Quantity,
  UnitPrice,
  LineltemTotal
from (
select        
  idn,
  Invoice,
  PurchaseOrderNumber,
  Quantity,
  UnitPrice,
  LineltemTotal,
  ID1,
  ISNULL(coalesce(ID1, first_value(ID1) OVER (partition by idgroup ORDER BY idn)),1) as id3
  from (
select idn,
  Invoice,
  PurchaseOrderNumber,
  Quantity,
  UnitPrice,
  LineltemTotal,
  ID1,
  count(ID1) OVER (order by idn) as  idgroup
  from (
SELECT row_number() over (order by (select null)) idn,
  Invoice,
  PurchaseOrderNumber,
  Quantity,
  UnitPrice,
  LineltemTotal,
 CASE WHEN 
left(PurchaseOrderNumber,2) like N'%PO%' THEN 
row_number() over (order by (select null)) ELSE null END AS ID1
from TABLE1) a) b) c

dbfiddle
result



idn
id
Invoice
PurchaseOrderNumber
Quantity
UnitPrice
LineltemTotal




1
1
120
P2037351818419
500
18.31
9155


2
2
120
PO20240091
null
null
null


3
2
120
P2037351818420
500
6.54
3270


4
3
120
PO20240091
null
null
null


5
3
120
P203735181823782
400
2.83
1132


6
3
120
4
null
null
null


7
4
120
PO20240060
null
null
null


8
4
120
P203735181823783
400
3.36
1344


9
4
120
5
null
null
null


10
5
120
PO20240060
null
null
null



